# Keep Footer at Bottom of Page using Server Side Includes

Tags: jquery, html, css, footer

I have a site I'm trying to create that includes multiple pages.  I am using server side includes to dump in the header and site contents bar on each page so I don't have to include the HTML in every page.

I got to a point where I wanted to include a footer and am struggling with how to force the footer to the bottom of the page, and have tried a lot of the suggestions found on Stack Overflow and either I'm missing something or need to try something different.

It seems like the height of the help contents (using JQuery accordion) is not being taken into consideration...?...or I don't have the proper formatting to push the footer to the bottom of the page instead of the screen.

Maybe there's a better way of doing what I'm trying to accomplish (pull in header and footer for each page without having to copy the HTML) or I'm missing something from the HTML and/or CSS.

A sample page that includes a footer bar can be found [here](https://gis.linncounty.org/webapps/auditor/landrecords__style/help/_pages/widgets/about/about.shtml).

Sample of the HTML for the above page is below...

```
<body>

<div class="page-content">

<!--#include file="../../../_includes/header.shtml"-->

<div class="container">
    <h2 class="container-header">About Widget</h2>
    <div>
        <p class="container-text">The About widget is located in the upper right-hand corner of the application, within the header, as shown below.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-header-figure-container">
        <figure>
            <img class="widget-header-figure-image" src="images/about.jpg" alt="AboutWidget">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption">About widget highlighted in red</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="container-text">The About widget provides a synopsis of the application as well as the layers included within the map.  Additional links that may be of interest are also provided.</p>
        <p class="container-text">Contact information for the <a class="link" href="http://linncounty.org/418/GIS-Division" target="_blank">GIS Division</a> and <a class="link" href="http://linncounty.org/292/Real-Estate-Services" target="_blank">Real Estate Division</a> can be found.  The Web AppBuilder Developer Edition version and application build date can be found at the bottom.</p>
    </div>

</div>

<footer>
<!--#include file="../../../_includes/footer.shtml"-->
</footer>

</div>

</body>
```

Sample CSS is below:

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    height: 100%; 
}

body {
    background-color: #d2d2d2;
    font-family: 'Cuprum';
    height: 100%;
}

.page-content {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#footer-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #797986;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would remove `height` from `body` and `html`, apply `min-height: 100vh; overflow: auto; padding-bottom: 150px; box-sizing: border-box` to `.page-content` to give it the height instead, clear the floated nav, pad the bottom to make room for the footer, and keep that padding from extending the height to `100vh + 150px`. I also changed your `footer` selector in the CSS to `footer` instead of the `id` since the `id` isn't in your code.

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  font-family: 'Cuprum';
  margin: 0;
}

.page-content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #797986;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="page-content">

<!--#include file="../../../_includes/header.shtml"-->

<div class="container">
    <h2 class="container-header">About Widget</h2>
    <div>
        <p class="container-text">The About widget is located in the upper right-hand corner of the application, within the header, as shown below.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-header-figure-container">
        <figure>
            <img class="widget-header-figure-image" src="images/about.jpg" alt="AboutWidget">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption">About widget highlighted in red</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="container-text">The About widget provides a synopsis of the application as well as the layers included within the map.  Additional links that may be of interest are also provided.</p>
        <p class="container-text">Contact information for the <a class="link" href="http://linncounty.org/418/GIS-Division" target="_blank">GIS Division</a> and <a class="link" href="http://linncounty.org/292/Real-Estate-Services" target="_blank">Real Estate Division</a> can be found.  The Web AppBuilder Developer Edition version and application build date can be found at the bottom.</p>
    </div>

</div>

<footer>
  footer
</footer>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the changes to the CSS worked great!  I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS, just curious what the main issue was?

Comment: defining `height: 100%` to `html,body` actually makes the height 100% of the browser viewport. You usually want to use `html { height: 100%; }` and `body { min-height: 100% }` instead but I find using `min-height: 100vh` on a content element works best. And the floated sidebar wasn't cleared so the height of the parent didn't respect the height of the sidebar. Look into "css clearfix" to learn more about that.